# Is there a better way of remembering previously given optional method arguments in Python?

Tags: python, class, methods, arguments

So I've been fiddeling around with classes as I try to make sense of them, and came across the need to have my methods remember previously given arguments. This was because I wanted to trigger a method without passing new arguments, and instead just use the same arguments from before.
Since I was triggering this from somewhere else I thought it would be easier to try and make the class remember the variables and use the memory if no new arguments was passed.

What I ended up with was basically this:

```
class someclass:
    def test(self, x=None):
        if x:
            self.x = "yes " + str(x)
        try:
            print(self.x)
        except AttributeError:
            pass

a = someclass()

a.test()
a.test()
a.test(5)
a.test()
a.test()
```

So the first two times it is called, `self.x` is not yet defined so it passes. Any time after that it remembers the 5 that was given only once.

So my question is mainly if there is a simpler/better way of writing this block, but also if this is somehow bad practice that will cause me problems later.

Comment: Yes that is an entirely valid approach. In fact, that is exactly what instance attributes are there for. They are there to store the `state` of your instance. In this case, your function updates the state of `self.x`to `"yes " + str(x)`. (I'm not sure what you want to achieve with the `try`, `except` clauses, but I presume that isn't important here)

Comment: Well the `try`,`except` is there for the first two times it is called and `self.x` is not yet defined. Without it I'd end up with an `AttributeError`. I was mainly looking for a way to avoid those lines, and looks like Taras Savchyn's answer provided me with just that.

Comment: If Taras Savchyn's answer solves your problem, then please mark it as the accepted answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do that using class attributes. Here we used class attribute `x` to store our default value first, and then to store previously entered value:

Code:

```
class someclass:
    x = None
    def test(self, x=x):
        if x:
            someclass.x = "yes " + str(x)
        if someclass.x:
            print(someclass.x)

a = someclass()

a.test()
a.test()
a.test(5)
a.test()
a.test()
```